# Encrypting some JSON values inside JSON packets

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have a requirement to encrypt/decrypt selected attribute values for some of the JSON packets that will flow through the API gateway. Is this possible using Bluemix API Management?

I have looked through the [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZFB2/welcome), but didn't find anything so maybe this is an undocumented feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to write a microservice or some app code to do this.

Comment: Ah, ok - do you know if functionality to encrypt/decrypt parts of the json is on the roadmap?